# JS Função com vários parametros que retorne um HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Atualizada:
Com base na resposta do SAM, deixem eu esclarecer o que preciso. Considerando apenas JS, quero uma variavel que guarde um texto da seguinte forma:

**var x = "texto qualquer"+função(y parametros)+"mais um pouco de texto e a função citada retorna um texto"**

É possível uma variável guardar um texto gerado por uma função concatenando com outros textos?

---

Bom dia pessoal!
Estou fazendo com JS um Array e cada "célula" desse array contem um código HTML enorme. Fiz isso para que cada "radio" que eu escolha no meu HTML mudasse o conteúdo ao lado.

Mas o código de cada array está ficando muito longo e feio na tela, cansativo de fazer e de manter também. Então pensei em passar tudo para uma função, já que boa parte do código HTML se repete e apenas o que muda eu passaria como parametro para a função.

Então meu array conteria um texto + função(x parametros) e esse array seria passado para um ID do meu HTML pelo comando document.getElementById().innerHTML;

```js
var racetrees = racetree[12];
racetree[2] = 
"<table class='enh_tear'>\
 <tr>\
 <td rowspan='2' class='icon_enh'><img src=img/enh_tree/enh_tree_ambidexterity.jpg></td>\
 <td colspan='4'><strong>Ambidexterity:</strong> You gain +1 to hit when dual-wielding or fighting unarmed.\
 Tier 2: Also gaisn +1% Dodge. Tier 3: Algo gains +1 damage.</td>\
<tr>\
 <td class='ap_cost'>AP Cost: 1</td>\
 <td class='level'>Ranks: 3</td>\
 <td class='progression'>Progression: 5</td>\
 <td class='requeriments'>Requires: Two Weapon Fighting (FEAT)</td>\
</tr>\
</table>"

function racetree(index){
document.getElementById("racetreetext").innerHTML = racetree[index];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Builder</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/racetype.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<section id="racetype">
 <p><input type="radio" name="race" onclick="racetree(0);">Aasimar</p>
</section>
 <section id="racetree">
 <span id="racetreetext"></span>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Eu quero passar como parametro apenas o nome do arquivo da imagem, deixando o caminho pre-escrito na função, o nome dentro da tag "strong", o texto após essa tag em outro parametro, o "1" do AP cost, o "3" de Ranks, etc...

Como eu faria essa função, e como eu passaria um longo texto como parametro em uma função?

Answer (score 0):

Crie um objeto com todos as strings (nomes das imagens e textos) separados por seção e numerados, desta forma:

```
var dados = {
   imagens: {
      1: "enh_tree_ambidexterity.jpg",
      2: "enh_tree_ambideity2.jpg"
   },

   strong: {
      1: "Ambidexterity",
      2: "Ambiterity2"
   },

   strongtxt: {
      1: "You gain +1 to hit when dual-wielding or fighting unarmed.",
      2: "You gain +2 to hit unarmed."
   },

   requires: {
      1: "Bla bla bla",
      2: "Two Weapon Fighting (FEAT)"
   }
}
```

Esse objeto `dados` (pode dar o nome que quiser) será usado como fonte de onde você irá tirar as informações a serem concatenadas na tabela dentro da função. Desta forma, a única coisa que você precisará passar como parâmetro para a função são números, tornando o processo bem mais fácil de escrever e administrar. No `onclick` você irá passar apenas os números referentes ao dado que quer puxar do objeto `dados`.

**Veja:**

```js
var dados = {
   imagens: {
      1: "enh_tree_ambidexterity.jpg",
      2: "enh_tree_ambidexterity2.jpg"
   },
   
   strong: {
      1: "Ambidexterity",
      2: "Ambidexterity2"
   },
   
   strongtxt: {
      1: "You gain +1 to hit when dual-wielding or fighting unarmed.",
      2: "You gain +2 to hit when dual-wielding or fighting unarmed."
   },

   requires: {
      1: "Bla bla bla",
      2: "Two Weapon Fighting (FEAT)"
   }
}


function racetree(img, str, strtxt, cost, rks, prog, req){

   img = dados.imagens[img]; // imagem
   str = dados.strong[str]; // texto tag strong
   strtxt = dados.strong[strtxt]; // texto após tag strong
   req = dados.requires[req]; // texto de "Requires"

   var tab = "<table class='enh_tear'>\
      <tr>\
      <td rowspan='2' class='icon_enh'><img src=img/enh_tree/"+ img +"></td>\
      <td colspan='4'><strong>"+ str +":</strong> "+ strtxt +"\
      Tier 2: Also gaisn +1% Dodge. Tier 3: Algo gains +1 damage.</td>\
   <tr>\
      <td class='ap_cost'>AP Cost: "+ cost +"</td>\
      <td class='level'>Ranks: "+ rks +"</td>\
      <td class='progression'>Progression: "+ prog +"</td>\
      <td class='requeriments'>Requires: "+ req +"</td>\
   </tr>\
   </table>";

   document.getElementById("racetreetext").innerHTML = tab;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="radio" name="race" onclick="racetree(1,1,1,1,3,5,2);">Aasimar</p>
<span id="racetreetext"></span>
```

Comment: Entendi! Muito obrigado! Porém, vou precisar criar várias tabelas como essa, e eu queria chamar apenas uma função no html. Logo eu queria que essa função que você criou ai, alimentasse uma variável. para eu poder chamar essa variável com todas as tabelas para o html com uma função menor.

Comment: Blz. A resposta foi só uma ideia que pode ser útil. Valeu!